# Rewrite url with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URL with multiple parameters, like this: /61252/sdfs
where /61252/ is category id, it selected from public/subcategory.php and 
/sdfs/, who is selected from public/post.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+) public/subcategory?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I am confused, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: an URL like this categoryid/postname/
categoryid in my example is subcategory?id=$1 , selected from public folder, and postname is an string selected from same folder but is another file, post.php

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) public/subcategory.php?id=$1&who=$2 [L]
```

Then in `subcategory.php` include `post.php`

You can't rewrite to 2 targets.

Comment: it is not working, maybe i can try to do it with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?

Comment: I created some like this: 

========== HTACCES ============

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+) public/subcategory?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+) public/subcategory?id=$1&post_name=$2 [NC,L]

============ PHP =========
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  echo $_GET['id'];
 }
 else if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['post_name'])){
  echo $_GET['post_name'];
 }

but shows only 'id'. Problem is in htacces, I deleted thirst part of script and worked , but thirst isn't.

Comment: The first rule overrides the second one. Put them in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea, that is you get all URL and send to the php file and you can use explode function in php to convert url string to array. So with array you can easy  to get the value as you want.

Comment: hmm, i will try